# How do I use Breadcrumbs-on-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, breadcrumbs

I'm very, very new to Ruby, Ruby on Rails, and even the OS that I use. I'd like to use [breadcrumbs-on-rails](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails). I added the gem, I've done `bundle install`, but I don't understand how to use it?

I've tried to copy and paste it to see if it works like that, but of course it doesn't work.
Do I need to replace "home" (:root_path) and "my" (:my_path) by something else?

Here's my `pages_controller.rb`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  add_breadcrumb "home", :root_path
  add_breadcrumb "my", :my_path
  def index
    add_breadcrumb "index", index_path
  end
end
```

And here's my `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'forum' => 'pages#home'
  get 'forum/:id-:name' => 'pages#index'
end
```

I've written the `<%= render_breadcrumbs %>` in the view too.

The error is : `undefined local variable or method 'index_path' for #< PagesController:0x0000561b24ad6200 >`

Doing `rake routes` gives me this:

[rake routes results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnOIv.png)

Can somebody kindly explain to me how it works, with all the details (if I have to change something, and if so, by what)? Sorry to ask such stupid questions!

Thank you.

Comment: what is the output for `rails routes`? What is the path helper? The path helpers provided in the docs are generalizations

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery Sorry I'm not sure to understand... is "path helper" something like "index_path" ? If so, what should I write instead ? "rails routes" doesn't do anything, does it ? I tried "rake routes", it basically repeats my route.rb file.

Comment: The path helper would be something like index_path, yes.  if you paste the output of running `rails routes` in your terminal, that should allow us to help better :D

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery "rails routes" doesn't do anything for me : it says "Error : Command 'routes' not recognized. Did you mean '$ rake routes' ?"

Comment: Yes, same thing just depending on your version of Rails

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery I added the image in the post.

Comment: Cpl more question, why do you call the controller pages, but the routes forum? What is the relationships(models) involved?

Comment: It was just a test I was doing @Int'lManOfCodingMystery. "forum" doesn't mean anything in particular in this project, I was just trying some things

Answer (score 0):

bienvenue chez Ruby and Rails, ami ;)

You are doing everything right. What you are doing wrong is that you are taking `index_path` literally. What the documentation meant is that replace index_path with path of the index method of your controller which is provided by default by rails and will be different for every controller, of course :)

The `index_path` for your `pages_controller` is `pages_path`, so you should do this in `pages_controller.rb`:

```
  def index
    add_breadcrumb "index", pages_path
  end
```

I hope it solves the issue.

Comment: and you don't need `add_breadcrumb "my", :my_path`. That is just an example for adding similar paths if needed. You don't need it.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you. But I tried it and it doesn't work. I tried to change things, see if it works but it doesn't seem to. It's no big deal, I'm going back to what I've learned to try again from 0.